# Questions about how inheritance affects Spring Controller classes when using a base controller class

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, inheritance, spring-mvc

If I use a base controller class in Spring MVC, do controllers defined as subclasses get separate instances of any private static objects defined in the base controller?

For example:

BaseController:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController
{

    private UserService userService;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);

    private static final Map<String, String> NameValueMap = Common.getNameValueMap();

    public final UserService getUserService()
    {
        return userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public final void setUserService(UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

}
```

ControllerA:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerA extends BaseController
{


}
```

ControllerB:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerB extends BaseController
{


}
```

1. Do `ControllerA` and `ControllerB` each have a separate instance of `NameValueMap`?
2. Does the `@Autowired userService` defined in the base controller mean that this does not need to be defined in `ControllerA` and `ControllerB`?
3. If the logger instance defined in the BaseController is used in `ControllerA` or `ControllerB` does it necessarily refer to the one defined for the `BaseController` because of this:

> LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class)

Answer (score 2):

Static is not inherited (although it seems so sometimes), and it's not (re)initialised for subclasses. Make those instance fields (and also make them `protected` rather than `private` if you want to access them in subclasses):

```
protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( getClass() );
protected final Map<String, String> NameValueMap = Common.getNameValueMap();
```

This way, every subclass will have an instance of those fields and will also be able to access it (note that for the Logger instantiation you are now able to use `getClass()`, which is an instance method and every subclass will provide its own `Class` object).

As for the `@Autowired` question, the general answer is that an annotation applies to subclasses if it's annotated itself with the (meta)annotation `@Inherited`. `@Autowired` is not, as far as I know.